# Docker can't connect to internet - connection reset by peer error

Tags: docker

I'm trying to get docker set up on my machine and for some reason docker hasn't been able to connect to the internet.
If anyone has any tips let me know! This is on the apple chip mac on Monterey.

The error is - Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": read tcp 192.168.65.4:59530->192.168.65.5:3128: read: connection reset by peer.

I have tried to re-download and re-install docker a ton, restarted my computer, have gone through tons of stack overflow/etc. tips but haven't been able to debug it. I've also changed wifi networks and removed SentinelOne. The error in the screenshot below is what I try to get if I try to login via the terminal, try and set up docker's onboarding container, or run a build.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08X3i.png)

Comment: try  (1) `docker run hello-world`  ,  and (2) `docker image rm -f hello-world`, and (3) `docker run hello-world` , if (1) ok , (3) ok,  then  try `docker pull python:3.8.16-slim-bullseye` if all ok , I guess problem is Dockerfile. (4) check `ifconfig` , show ip , (5) `cat /etc/hosts`

Comment: The url `https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/python/manifests/3.10` requires authorization. Do you have provided it on your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstall again and re-download an older version, version 4.12.0 worked for me after being stuck on this issue for days

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-17120-ce-mac49-2018-01-19

Comment: I've had the same issue and installing an older version (Docker 4.14.1) resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

It is so strange...
But I got this issue during "docker pull" command when some other docker image was running at this moment.
After I had stopped all running docker containers "docker pull" has started working normally.
So, possible solution - **Stop all running docker containers and then execute "docker pull" command.**